# Loop to generate random cells in a table not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table created in HTML using the table tag. I am trying to randomly select few cells from this table using a function in javascript. I use a for loop for iteration. Please see the code below. In this code, my for loop limit is 300, so i expect that randomly any 300 cells will be selected. However, only 3-4 are being selected. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
function random_Pattern() {
    var p;
    var q;
    for (var r = 0; r < 301; r++) {
        p = Math.floor(Math.random() * grid_width)+1;
        q = Math.floor(Math.random() * grid_height)+1;
        var cell = document.getElementById("myTableID").rows[p].cells[q];
        cell.style.backgroundColor = "red";

    }

}
```

Comment: What are `grid_width` and `grid_height`? Do you see any errors in your browser console when you run this function? Could you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), such as a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: This looks reasonably right to me. It won't be 300 (since you can get duplicates) but it should be a lot more than 3 or 4. Can you post an example on jsbin.com or jsfiddle so we can play around with what your problem is?

Comment: you can log the cell number generated by your function to make sure your random function is not repeating the same values

Comment: I think your grid_width & grid_height values exceed far than 300 and thats why majority of the random distribution is above 300.

Comment: Really good chance it is what @mohkhan says - are grid_width and grid_height maybe the dimensions in pixels rather than cell count? That like the sort of mistake I've made a dozen times.

Comment: I see that Majid (2nd ans) below already tried this code: http://jsbin.com/atukuf/1/edit  I will try to change the dimensions again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be some problem with your cell selection code, because the rest works just fine:
http://jsbin.com/atukuf/1/edit

Of course it is possible that some cells are selected multiple times and the count would not go up to 300 distinct cells, but it could not be as few as 3-4 that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Not much information to work with in the question, but here's one idea. It appears that `p` and `q` are backwards: `p` is based on `grid_width` but is used to index the rows (vertical). Similarly, `q` is based on `grid_height` but is used to index cells (horizontal).

If `grid_width` and `grid_height` are very different this could result in your selecting only a small subset of cells.

I think you should have:

```
p = Math.floor(Math.random() * grid_height)+1;
q = Math.floor(Math.random() * grid_width)+1;
var cell = document.getElementById("myTableID").rows[p].cells[q];
```